# Why SRP is not plaintext-equivalent?

Tags: algorithm, security, srp-protocol

About the SRP Protocol:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_remote_password_protocol

I can see that the generation of the session key (K) is perfectly safe, but in the last step the user sends proof of K (M). If the network is insecure and the attacker in the midlle captures M, he would be able to authenticate without having K. right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### A little background

**Well known values (established beforehand):**

```
  n    A large prime number. All computations are performed modulo n.
  g    A primitive root modulo n (often called a generator).
```

**The users password is established as:**

```
x = H(s, P)
v = g^x 

  H()  One-way hash function
  s    A random string used as the user's salt
  P    The user's password
  x    A private key derived from the password and salt
  v    The host's password verifier
```

**The authentication:**

```
+---+------------------------+--------------+----------------------+
|   | Alice                  | Public Wire  | Bob                  |
+---+------------------------+--------------+----------------------+
| 1 |                        |        C --> | (lookup s, v)        |
| 2 | x = H(s, P)            | <-- s        |                      |
| 3 | A = g^a                |        A --> |                      |
| 4 |                        | <-- B, u     | B = v + g^b          |
| 5 | S = (B - g^x)^(a + ux) |              | S = (A · v^u)^b      |
| 6 | K = H(S)               |              | K = H(S)             |
| 7 | M[1] = H(A, B, K)      |     M[1] --> | (verify M[1])        |
| 8 | (verify M[2])          | <-- M[2]     | M[2] = H(A, M[1], K) |
+---+------------------------+--------------+----------------------+

    u    Random scrambling parameter, publicly revealed
  a,b    Ephemeral private keys, generated randomly and not publicly revealed
  A,B    Corresponding public keys
  m,n    The two quantities (strings) m and n concatenated
    S    Calculated exponential value 
    K    Session key
```

### **The answer to your question:**

As you can see, both parties calculate K (=the session key) separately, based upon the values available to each of them.
If Alice's password P entered in Step 2 matches the one she originally used to generate v, then both values of S will match.

The actual session key K is however never send over the wire, only the proof that both parties have successfully calculated the same session key. So a man-in-the middle could resend the proof, but since he does not have the actual session key, he would not be able to do anything with the intercepted data.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is only valid for a certain K.

**Without MITM:**

```
Alice <-K-> Bob
```

Alice produces a proof for K and Bob accepts it

**With MITM:**

```
Alice <-K1-> Eve <-K2-> Bob
```

Alice produces a proof for K1 but when Eve presents it to Bob he doesn't accept it because it doesn't fit K2.

Comment: I don't understand.... if Eve knows the proof of K (M) read from Alice, can't Eve just present the same M to Bob? I can see the secure generation of K, the authentication step is that seems vulnerable to MITM.

Comment: I haven't worked through the details of SRP, but one simple example where both alice and bob know the same password could be alice sending bob Hash(password+K1). And bob checking if it matches Hash(password+K2). The actual protocol is a bit more complicated to gain additional security properties.

Comment: The beauty of the SRP-protocol is that bob does not know the actual password, only a non-reversible derived value.